# Selecting Last change value per group

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select the last change value per group.

I have a table

**MMID column is incremental**

```
MMID  GID  MID  Value  Bundle DateEntered
1      1    1      1     2       17/8/15 05:05:04
2      1    2      2     3       16/8/15 05:05:06
3      1    3      3     2       15/8/15 05:05:07
4      1    1      0     2       18/8/15 05:05:08
5      2    2      1     1       18/8/15 05:05:05
6      2    2      2     2       18/8/15 06:06:06
7      2    4      3     1       17/8/15 06:06:06
8      2    4      3     2       18/8/15 06:06:07
```

Here, I want the last change 'Value' in the last 24 hour(Having Date 18th August).
From the below query, I can get that. But even if the bundle value is changed, then I get that row.
But I want only rows when 'Value' is changed, or 'Value and Bundle' are changed. But not only when Bundle is changed

```
Desired output

MMID  GID  MID  Value  Bundle DateEntered

4      1    1      0     2       18/8/15 05:05:08
6      2    2      2     2       18/8/15 06:06:06
```

The query I tried is :

```
select yt1.*
from Table1 yt1
left outer join Table1 yt2
on (yt1.GID = yt2.GID and yt1.MID = yt2.MID
and yt1.MMID < yt2.MMID)
where yt2.MMID is null and yt2.GID is null and yt2.MID is null and yt1.DateEntered > '2015-08-18 00:00:00' ;
```

The output i get from here is:

```
MMID  GID  MID  Value  Bundle DateEntered

4      1    1      0     2       18/8/15 05:05:08
6      2    2      2     2       18/8/15 06:06:06
8      2    4      3     2       18/8/15 06:06:07
```

I should not be getting the last row here.

Can anyone tell me what should I change here.

Comment: Why does your query reference "Table1" and "Table2"?   Is there more than one table?   It doesn't seem like your query should work at all.  You have " yt1.MMID < yt2.MMID" and yet you also have "where yt2.MMID is null".   This query should never return any results.

Comment: @TabAlleman Sorry it is Table 1 only. I edited.

Comment: @TabAlleman No it works because it is a left join, not a inner join

Comment: You should take a look at this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Not really following the logic of your attempt, but here is how I would get the desired results:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GID, MID ORDER BY MMID) AS rn
  FROM Table
)
, cte2 AS (
SELECT t1.* FROM cte t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
 ON t1.GID=t2.GID
 AND t1.MID=t2.MID
 AND t1.value<>t2.value
 AND t1.rn=t2.rn+1
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte2
WHERE MMID=(
  SELECT TOP 1 MMID
  FROM cte2 c2
  WHERE cte2.GID=c2.GID
  AND cte2.MID=c2.MID
  ORDER BY MMID DESC
)
```

NB: If you don't want to include the rn column in the final results, use a column list instead of SELECT *.